# No option to suppress StyleCop warnings in context menu

Tags: visual-studio-2010, stylecop

I have just installed StyleCop v4.7.36.0 and am using Visual Studio 2010.

When I run StyleCop on the solution or individual project the warnings are being correctly reported in the Error List window.

When I right click, however there is no option to suppress the warning message(s).

[image]

Is there any way to fix this? I really don't want to have to resort to manually editing the `GlobalSuppressions.cs` file.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? Nothing I've tried has worked. If I go to Tools > Customize and select the Commands tab and then select Context Menu and look up 'Other Context Menus | Error List' I can see it in there (Supress Message...) but it does not actually show up when right clicking style cop warnings.

Comment: Nope its still broken for me

Answer (score 1):

Right click on your project inside visual studio project explorer. And then to StyleCop settings. You can disable any warning you want from the window that is shown.
You can find the specific warning from the code as it appears in your picture. So for example to disable the first warning show, you'd go to warning 1633 in the StyleCop settings window and just uncheck what you want.